# WPS fix import of org.geotools.util.factory.GeoTools

Tags: geoserver, import, wps, importerror

I need to import the org.geotools.util.factory.GeoTools

```
import org.geotools.util.factory.GeoTools;
```

but the compiler has issues finding the import. I set up my project using maven with the following dependencies:

```
<properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <gt.version>20.0</gt.version>  <!-- change to GeoTools version -->
     <gs.version>2.14.0</gs.version>  <!-- change to GeoServer version -->
   </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
       <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
       <version>${gt.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
       <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
       <version>${gs.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>gs-main</artifactId>
       <version>${gs.version}</version>
       <classifier>tests</classifier>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.11</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
       <artifactId>mockrunner</artifactId>
       <version>0.3.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opengis</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

My project also makes use of `import org.geotools.util.logging.Logging;` and this works. All other imports work good. This is the only one that fails. Unfortunately googling didn't help me. Is this a version issue? Is this import renamed or deprecated? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that class is at `org.geotools.factory.GeoTools` in all versions prior to the master branch, where it has been moved.

I suspect you are mixing and matching between [**stable**](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/factory.html) and [**latest**](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/factory.html) documents, unless you are using GeoTools version 20-SNAPSHOT (or later) you should look at stable.

Comment: I am trying to use and modify this code: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/ClipProcess.java This is the latest I guess and the import all work in my project except the one I am asking for. So I don't really get your comment?

Comment: your pom says it is using 20.0 not 20-SNAPSHOT so it will not compile code on the master branch.

Comment: Hm ok so changing this would resolve this issue? I thought I had to give it the version of Geoserver I am running and I am running at 20.0 not snapshot ..

Comment: That is correct, you need to use https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/20.x/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/ClipProcess.java if you are using GeoTools 20.0 not https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/ClipProcess.java